# Changing Variable value from another class

Tags: java, android, andengine

I have an integer(`levelstatus`) in class A(`LevelSelectScene`) and I want to change it in class B(`GameScene`), is it possible?

here is my code:

(Code in GameScene)

```
public class levelComplete()
{

levelSelectScene.getInstance.levelstatus=1;

}
```

`LevelSelectScene` has an public integer `levelstatus`.

and after an event happens, `levelComplete` will trigger and will change the value of `levelstatus` from null to 1.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.

Make your `levelstatus` variable  as `static`.

Because I guess you need to change that variable in each level class.

That means,you are wanting to access that variable through out the whole Game(All levels).

And also,Declare that variable in a `Util` class(proposing a name `LevelUtil`),Since it wont attach to a single level.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to change the value any where in the project(that is in any class) since the variable is declared as `public levelstatus`.

If you want to change the value of the variable in many places and the new value should be the modification of previously changed value, the you should declare the variable as `public static levelstatus`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is more appropriate if you look into SharedPrefences of the Android API.

[Check it here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

It could be used across the whole project of yours and it is handy in those kind of cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can access your variable as a public static.

Definition:

```
public  static Boolean isPremium;
```

Access (do not forget `import`) :

```
your_class.isPremium
```